# Bootstrap dropdown-menu inside navbar works incorrectly at 767px screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Dropdown-menu inside navbar works correctly until screen width is bellow or above 767px.
But if screen width is **exactly 767px**, then dropdown-menu inside navbar is narrow, like at wide screens, although the navigation is for small screens, and it looks very ugly.

Please look at image.

I use Bootstrap 3.3.7

Could you please give me any advice how to fix this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: media querys. Use them. Bootstrap has the breaking point at 767px. There is no Image

Comment: Img is at [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIzOQ.jpg)

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Cannot reproduce your menu issue when adjusting ss to 767 here but it is using version 3.3.7 https://jsfiddle.net/tghLetvt/1/

Comment: I use bootstrap 3.3.7 too, and at jsfiddle that Travis Action linked I had exactly the same problem at Page Width: 767px. I tried it at Chrome, Firefox and Edge and at all three browsers I had the same problem at 767px page width.